# How to install alternative version of Python beside distro supplied?

Tags: linux, installation, python

Is there any official way to install a specific version of Python, at least `2.6`, manually into my chosen directory? I do not necessarily have root privileges on the host that I am installing to.

After I complete the Python installation, I will need to install `pip` for it. It is essential to me that the system supplied Python (2.4.3 packaged with CentOS 5) is completely ignored for all my purposes. In essence, my entire Python and pip installation procedure has to behave as if no previous version of python is installed on the system.

Do I compile it from source, or can I have some form of package I can just extract somewhere and run Python from? I prefer the latter, as I try to avoid installing development software stack on the host (it is a server, not a dev workstation).

Comment: use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Comment: Doesn't virtualenv require python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download one of the source tarballs on [this page](http://python.org/download/).

Then, unpack it, `cd` into the directory, and follow the directions in section 2.2 of the [python online manual](http://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html).

If you want it to install to, for example, `/usr/bin` instead of the default (`/usr/local/bin` in ubuntu/debian), then instead of `./configure`, type `./configure --prefix=/usr` when told to use it in the guide.

For in your `$HOME/bin` directory, use `--prefix=$HOME`.

If it doesn't exist, add `$HOME/bin` to your `$PATH` like this:

`$ export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`

This may already be in your `.bashrc` in ubuntu, and others. If it is, when you next log in, `$HOME/bin` will be added to your `$PATH` automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ALTINSTALL` for alternative installation to not replace your default Python3.

```
tar zxvf Python-2.6.5.tgz
cd Python-2.6.5
./configure
make
make altinstall
```

For further info check the relevant [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/using/unix.html#building-python). Take note if the instructions are for the version you are about to install.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This seems like a good answer but for anyone unfamiliar with Linux, these commands might be a bit opaque. You may want to consider adding a brief explanation of the steps you're taking and why in addition to the commands themselves.

Answer (score 1):

For that, I believe you would need to compile from source and use the `--prefix` option.

1. Download Python
2. Untar `tar -xvf python*.tar.bz2`
3. CD to the directory: `cd python`
4. Compile/install: `./configure --prefix=/home/$(whoami)/desired_folder && make && make install`
5. Add it to your `path` to be able to invoke it.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a job for virtualenv: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

You can install it with pip: `pip install virtualenv`, however you will need privileges on the machine for this. If you do not have machine privileges you can install it locally (copy-pasted from the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)):

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ python virtualenv.py myVE
```

Edit:
By itself virtualenv does not install new versions of python, you have to have it installed elsewhere as other answers have mentioned, then specify the path to your custom build with `-p /path/to/bin/python` when creating an environment. What it does do is make it easy to keep the environment separate from the rest of the system.

Comment: That's the thing - I don't have python on the host, and I am in no position to use package manager to install it. In fact I don't even have development tools to build it from source, but that restriction is more relaxed - I can install these [dev] tools. Anyhow, I will have to build and install python first, then pip, then virtualenv. Thanks for the instructions on virtualenv usage though.

Comment: I did not know about virtualenv. it looks neat. But how is this different from a `chroot`?

Comment: A chroot prevents the application from acessing anything outside its jail. virtualenv does not do this; it only isolates your python code from the system's python binaries and modules. Thus you can log to /var/log, call external binaries from /usr/bin and do anything a non-chrooted app can do.

Comment: I think he was asking for principal difference, in context of isolating Python. To that end, preventing application from accessing anything outside its "jail" is irrelevant. Even a chrooted program sees `/var/log`, `/usr/bin`, etc, it's just that the actual data that is available addressing `/var/log` and `/usr/bin` in this case, may be different -- it doesn't have to be the same `/var/log` and `/usr/bin`. You *change* the root, but you can't get rid of it. Jailing is a loose term which can describe something that can be done with `chroot`, but the two have a bit different scope.